# How to select the most recent browsing window in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I run the following code, it opens two browsing windows; the second is automatically open when the code hit the 'submitOrder' button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://example.com'
browser.get(url)    
browser.find_element_by_id('submitOrder').click()
```

Now I have to hit the 'checkout' button in the second (i.e, most recent browsing window). But the following code gives error that no such element.

```
browser.find_element_by_id('checkout').click()
```

How can I select the most recent browsing window (i.e., not previous one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clicking on checkout button, you'll first have to switch to the window to which that button belongs to and then perform action on that button.

```
driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

or

```
driver.switch_to_window("windowName")
```

*windowName Details*

```
All calls to driver will now be interpreted as being directed to the particular window. But how do you know the window’s name? Take a look at the javascript or link that opened it:

<a href="somewhere.html" target="windowName">Click here to open a new window</a>
```

For more details, refer to http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: thanks for your effort. btw how can i know windowName?

Comment: You can get it in the link mentioned above. Updating answer by putting  details. If `windowName` doesn't applicable in your case, you can use `handle`. And accept answer, if it helped you :)